# Create an array from two tables with a single entry

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables t1, t2. Each of them have only a single row and single column

How can I construct a json object from these two tables in snowflake?

select *
from t1

returns A

select *
from t2

return B

and I want
[A, B]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [ARRAY_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_agg.html)

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT A  FROM t1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT B  FROM t2
)
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(A)
FROM cte;
```

---

If it is guaranteed they have only single row then "array constructor" could be used:

```
SELECT [t1.A, t2.B] AS result
FROM t1
CROSS JOIN t2;
```